# test class fail for LeadShare: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: unit-test, sharing, record-access-level

i'm doing a test classe and run into an issue with the object LeadShare. So here it is:

```
@isTest
public class Test_LeadUtility {
    @testSetup static void setup(){
               String corporateBusiness = 'Corporate Business';
        
        String massBusiness = 'Mass Business';
        
        Profile p = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator' or name='Administrador do sistema' limit 1];
        
        User u1 = new User(alias = 'test123', email='test1@fake.pt', FirstName='test1',
                          emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing1', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                          localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, country='United States',
                          sfid__c = 'P.123',subsfid__c = 'P.123.456',
                          timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='test1@fake.pt', negocio__c = massBusiness);
        
        
         User u2 = new User(FirstName='test2', LastName='Testing123', UserName='test3@fake.pt', SFIDrule__c = 'SFID a partir da tabela Corporate',
                           Email='test3@fake.pt', Alias='test2', emailencodingkey='UTF-8', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                           localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, country='United States', timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',
                           negocio__c = corporateBusiness);      
        
        insert new List<User>{u1, u2};
            
        NIF_Corporate__c nif1 = new NIF_Corporate__c (Name='507779878', BusinessUnit__c='Activo');
        NIF_Corporate__c nif2 = new NIF_Corporate__c (Name='220387796', BusinessUnit__c='Activo');
        
        
        
        
        System.runAs(u1){
            insert new List<NIF_Corporate__c>{nif1, nif2};
                
                
                
            Account a = new Account(Name='Testing0', NIF__c='507779878', BillingPostalCode='1111-222', DoorNumber__c='1', BillingCountry='Portugal', OwnerId=u1.Id);
            insert a;
            
            Contact cont1 = new Contact (LastName = 'TestContact', OwnerId = u1.Id, AccountId = a.Id);
            Contact cont2 = new Contact (LastName = 'TestContact2', OwnerId = u1.Id, AccountId = a.Id);
            List<Contact> cList = new List<Contact>();
            cList.add(cont1);
            cList.add(cont2);
            System.runAs(u1){
                insert cList;
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    @isTest static void testInsert(){
        User u1 = [select id from User where email='test1@fake.pt']; 
        Account a = [select id from Account where Name='Testing0'];
        Lead ld1 = new Lead(
            LastPartnerName__c = u1.id,
            LastPartnerOwner__c = u1.id,
            Channel_Manager__c = u1.id,
            ownerid = u1.id,
            SUBSFID__c = 'S.RMF.019',
            LastName = 'Mr Bean',
            Company = 'Acme',
            DoorNumber__c = '2',
            PostalCode = '2500-067',
            SFID_Principal__c = 'S.RMF.019',
            Conta__c = a.id
        );
        
        System.debug('testInsert u1: ' + u1);
        
        System.debug('testInsert a: ' + a);
        
        // AccountTeamMember at1 = new AccountTeamMember(AccountId=a1.id, UserId=u1.Id, TeamMemberRole='Consultor Comercial', AccountAccessLevel = 'Read');
        AccountTeamMember at2 = new AccountTeamMember(AccountId=a.id, UserId=u1.Id, TeamMemberRole='Coordenador Comercial', AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit');
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        System.runAs(u1){
            insert ld1;
            System.debug('testInsert ld1: ' + ld1);
            
            insert new List<AccountTeamMember>{at2};
            System.debug('testInsert at2: ' + at2);
            
            
            LeadShare lsh = new LeadShare(
                LeadAccessLevel = 'read',
                LeadId = ld1.id,
                UserOrGroupId = u1.id
            );
            
            insert lsh;
            System.debug('testInsert lsh: ' + lsh);
            
            AccountTeamMember atm = new AccountTeamMember (AccountId=a.Id, UserId=u1.Id, TeamMemberRole='Gestor de Cliente');
            
            insert atm;
        }
        
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

The errors:

20:08:30:698 EXCEPTION_THROWN [72]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

20:08:30:713 EXCEPTION_THROWN [91]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []
and the lines are:

// line 72

```
   AccountTeamMember at2 = new AccountTeamMember(AccountId=a.id, UserId=u1.Id, TeamMemberRole='Coordenador Comercial', AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit');
```

// line 91

```
  insert lsh;
```

weird, because i thought i'd have all the priveleges, with runAs. I used the normal interface, and a user with that profile, and all the operations run smoothly.

Until those errors, the debugs get me the expected records: User and Account. Actually, just commenting the insertion  of LeadShare, it also works without errors.

**Edit 1:**

In https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337167&type=1&mode=1 i see this message regards lack of ownership of a record. But this couldn't apply, because all inserts are done inside a runAs() statement. And this user has permissions  to insert and edit all records, of all recordtypes: it's an admin profile

[image]

Now i thought maybe something's wrong with this user. So i am one of those admins, and i can do all of these operations in the Salesforce interface. So i replaced the user search with:

```
User u1 = [select id from user where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

same errors, at the same lines. And thats the same user (mine) that did those 2 shares in the picture

Comment: Hi Luis, one thing to consider is that `runAs` method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing as seen on [apex reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm). So have you checked if the logged in user has access? Apex generally runs in system mode but I think is worth checking that as well.

Comment: Your Account `testing0` is already owned by User1 when you inserted it. Thus, you can't make User1 an accountTeam member (at2) for an account it already owns; you could make User2 an ATM though

Comment: wow, that was it: if you already own a record, you can't own its share. Using the second user for that, really worked!. And for good measure, i reviewed permissions. Thank you both!!